# memory size of Python data structure

Tags: python, memory, data-structures, memory-management

How do I find out the memory size of a Python data structure? I'm looking for something like:

```
sizeof({1:'hello', 2:'world'})
```

It is great if it counts every thing recursively. But even a basic non-recursive result helps. Basically I want to get a sense of various implementation options like tuple v.s. list v.s. class in terms of memory footprint. It matters because I'm planning to have millions of object instantiated.

My current dev platform is CPython 2.6.

Comment: That's going to be a *really* slow program, unless you have a lot of memory. Plus the size of the lookup table is going to be pretty huge (millions of objects?). Just sayin'

Comment: [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) is a good alternative to using classes as the space required by each instance is the same as a tuple. If you have a lot of instances of one class, you should look into [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at the [`sys.getsizeof`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) function. According to the documentation, it returns the size of an object in bytes, as given by the object's `__sizeof__` method.

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219162/daniel-stutzbach) pointed out in a comment, it's not recursive; it only counts bytes occupied by the object itself, not other objects it refers to. [This recipe for a recursive computation](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) is linked to by the Python 3 documentation.

Comment: This version works well for Python 2: https://gist.github.com/durden/0b93cfe4027761e17e69c48f9d5c4118