# pickle and python data structure

Tags: python, pickle

I have some data stored in a tree in memory and I regularly store the tree into disk using pickle. 
Recently I noticed that the program using a large memory, then I checked saved pickle file, it is around 600M, then I wrote an other small test program loading the tree back into memory, and I found that it would take nearly 10 times memory(5G) than the size on disk, is that normal? And what's the best way to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not normal.  I suspect your tree is bigger than you think.   Write some code to walk it and add up all the space used (and count the nodes).

See [memory size of Python data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471559/memory-size-of-python-data-structure)

Also what exactly are you asking?  Are you surprised that a 600M data structure on disk is 5G in memory.  That's not particularly surprising.  Pickle compresses the data so you expect it to be smaller on disk.  It's smaller by a factor of 10 (roughly) which is pretty good.

If you're surprised by the size of your own data that's another thing.

Comment: I am surprised that the file is 600M on disk, but loading into memory it takes 5G, you said pickle will compress it, that makes sense. But it raises another question, the tree is basically a prefix tree(trie) used for store url(string), it should not be larger than directly storing all urls in disk, right? After compress, it can only be smaller, But sometimes, the tree is larger than url list file (I am not storing other things in the tree).

Comment: BTW, thank you for your reply, and the link is also very useful.

Comment: Trees take (a little) more room than storing lists.  Trees have to have all the tree structure information as well as the information that you would store if you just store a list.   Trees and other data structures represent a time vs space trade off.  You can save space at the expense of time or vice versa (you can save time in storing the data or retrieving it).  It shouldn't be an enormous amount more.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the tree version of the data was much bigger though.  The smaller the data you store in each tree node the greater the tree structure overhead will be.   

Another thing to watch out for is unbalanced trees.. but they shouldn't be causing you the size problems you are seeing. 

Also see this post.  http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/
(pickle is good for complex python data-structs though).

Comment: I am going to calculate the memory to see the result. It is true that there are only a string (a few characters) in each node, and number of nodes is in the power of 7~8. That might be the reason.  Before that I have another question, I searched online, it said pickle is not thread-safe, so what will happen if I am dumping it while writing new things to it?

Comment: Very weird stuff I imagine.   Absolutely shouldn't be doing it cause you could "interleave" your data.  Consider taking a look at the queue module and threads and have a dedicated writer thread.  Or check out the mutex module (but watch out for deadlock).  Or consider using the builtin sqlite3 module  with thread safety turned on (need a DB connection for each thread).

Comment: What do you mean by "interleave", could you give an example? Actually I am not counting on the pickled file, because I am only using it as an intermediate backup. Previously I used lock to protect the tree from being simultaneously writing and write to disk. But now since I have 60 threads (maybe more), each reads/writes to the tree, if I still use lock, if will make all the threads block while the main thread is pickling the tree to the disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106778/discussion-between-demented-hedgehog-and-1a1a11a).